# Mongo C# Driver 2.7 - _t discriminator missing

Tags: c#, mongodb, discriminator, derived-types

after updating to version 2.7 of the MongoDB C# official driver my code seems to have stopped working.
I have a Nofitication class with 2 derived classes: NewFriendshipRequestNotification and FriendshipRequestAcceptedNotification. The code is the following:

```
[CollectionName("Notification")]
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(FriendshipRequestAcceptedNotification), typeof(NewFriendshipRequestNotification))]
public class Notification : MongoEntity
{
    [BsonRequired]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
    public NotificationType Type { get; protected set; }

    [BsonRequired]
    public string TargetUserId { get; set; }

    [BsonRequired]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [BsonRequired]
    public bool IsRead { get; set; } = false;

    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public DateTime? ReadTimestamp { get; set; }

    public Notification()
    {
        Type = NotificationType.Generic;
    }
}

public class NewFriendshipRequestNotification : Notification
{
    [BsonRequired]
    public string RequestingUserId { get; set; }

    [BsonRequired]
    public string RequestingUsername { get; set; }

    public NewFriendshipRequestNotification()
    {
        Type = NotificationType.NewFriendshipRequest;
    }
}

public class FriendshipRequestAcceptedNotification : Notification
{
    [BsonRequired]
    public string AcceptingUserId { get; set; }

    [BsonRequired]
    public string AcceptingUsername { get; set; }

    public FriendshipRequestAcceptedNotification()
    {
        Type = NotificationType.FriendshipRequestAccepted;
    }
}
```

Before this update, when I inserted a NewFriendshipRequestNotification notification, the document in the Notification collection had a `"_t": "NewFriendshipRequestNotification"` discriminator field, thanks to the attribute `[BsonKnownTypes]` on the base class. Now it doesn't.
Anyone has any idea why?